# Downloaded zip file is invalid

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to download (and later extract) a zip file from my dropbox account using this code

```
URL url = new URL("-");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

try (InputStream stream = con.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(stream, Paths.get(parent.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "zippedCache.zip"));
}
```

The file I'm trying to download is a folder with another folder in it (empty). When I attempt to open the zipped folder, I get something along the lines of "cannot open the folder the compressed zipped folder is invalid" (translated using Google translator). When I unzip it, it's empty.

Can anyone explain what the problem here is?

Edit: Also, the zip folder is empty when I download it using Java, however downloading it normally through a web browser works fine.

Comment: Please, add printStackTrace

Comment: No error is being thrown, I have tested this already.

Comment: Perhaps the initial URL is giving you back an HTTP redirect to the actual file binary URL or an HTTP 4xx error because it's requiring some sort of cookie. I would print out the response as text and look at the headers to see what's going on.

Comment: I would doublecheck on encoding UTF-8.

Comment: The problem was on my side, the url was partly incorrect (I had dl=0 instead of dl=1).

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your code again using a `HttpURLConnection`. This should work out.

For using `Https` you would need something like `urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory` or similar.

Comment: Tested using HttpURLConnection, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read the `InputStream` in parts into a `byte` array and write into a `FileOutputStream`. It's simpler I think.

Example:

```
InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("anything.zip");
while (stream.read(buffer) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer);
}
```